# android Color class - strange behavior, internal rounding error?

Tags: java, android, colors, internal

i have got a simple color int like `0x8833aacc`
if i now use `Color.colorToHSV` to create HSV value of it,
and then use `Color.HSVToColor` to get the int back, it is slightly different!
**`the red value decreases by 1`**

but it does this not everytime, e.g. when using `0x8830aacc` everythings ok, why?
my example code to show this:

```
final float[] current_hsv = new float[3];
float current_alpha = 1.0f;

private int GetColor()
{
    return Color.HSVToColor((int)(current_alpha * 255.0f), current_hsv);
}

private void SetColor(int color)
{
    Color.colorToHSV(color, current_hsv);
    current_alpha = (float)Color.alpha(color) / 255.0f;
}

private void Test()
{
    int color = 0x8833aacc;
    SetColor(color);
    int g = GetColor();

    //convert to hex, you'll see the red value decreased by 1!!!
    Log.i("Test", "color: " + String.format("%08x", color) + " got color: " + String.format("%08x", g));
}
```

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it myself:
there is defenitely a bug inside androids `Color.colorToHSV` or `Color.HSVToColor`.
im now using oracles `HSBToRGB` and `RGBToHSB` implementations,
and they dont have this issue.

(for those who don't know: HSB is [hue] [saturation] [brightness]
and [brightness] is the same as [value] from HSV - so there is no difference)
now everything is working fine :)